# Installing Torch7. iPython installation error (mac)

Tags: macos, lua, ipython, canopy, torch

I'm trying to install Torch7 on my mac, however the installation halts at this point:

```
Not updating your shell profile.
You might want to 
add the following lines to your shell profile:

export PATH=/Users/khsiddiqui/torch/install/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/khsiddiqui/torch/install/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
export    DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/khsiddiqui/torch/install/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Not sure what it means. Further above I received the following output

```
echo "Error: could not find ipython in PATH. Do you have it installed?"
   fi
```

However iPython is installed as I can confirm:

```
No update necessary, 'ipython' is up-to-date.
ipython-3.0.0-3.egg was installed on: Thu Apr  9 18:12:32 2015


kamransiquisMBP:torch khsiddiqui$ env | grep PATH
PATH=/Users/khsiddiqui/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/opt/X11/bin:
/usr/texbin
```

*Attempting to locate the .bashrc file*

```
%edit .bashrc
WARNING: Argument given (.bashrc) can't be found as a variable or as a filename.
```

`kamransiquisMBP:torch khsiddiqui$ ls -ld ~/.*
drwxr-xr-x+ 43 khsiddiqui  staff    1462 12 Apr 01:15 /Users/khsiddiqui/.
drwxr-xr-x   6 root        admin     204 19 Oct 17:34 /Users/khsiddiqui/..
-r--------   1 khsiddiqui  staff       7 19 Oct 17:34 /Users/khsiddiqui/.CFUserTextEncoding
-rw-r--r--@  1 khsiddiqui  staff   16388 26 Mar 23:59 /Users/khsiddiqui/.DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x   3 khsiddiqui  staff     102  8 Sep  2014 /Users/khsiddiqui/.R
-rw-r--r--   1 khsiddiqui  staff  728832  2 Apr 17:21 /Users/khsiddiqui/.RData
-rw-r--r--   1 khsiddiqui  staff    1101 20 Oct 02:58 /Users/khsiddiqui/.Rapp.history
-rw-r--r--   1 khsiddiqui  staff    6314  2 Apr 17:21 /Users/khsiddiqui/.Rhistory
drwx------  22 khsiddiqui  staff     748 12 Apr 01:25 /Users/khsiddiqui/.Trash
-rw-------   1 khsiddiqui  staff    1860  9 Apr 22:15 /Users/khsiddiqui/.bash_history
drwxr-xr-x   4 khsiddiqui  staff     136  9 Apr 17:57 /Users/khsiddiqui/.cache
drwx------  18 khsiddiqui  staff     612 12 Apr 20:09 /Users/khsiddiqui/.canopy
drwxr-xr-x   3 khsiddiqui  staff     102 12 Apr 01:15 /Users/khsiddiqui/.conda
drwxr-xr-x   2 khsiddiqui  staff      68 12 Apr 01:11 /Users/khsiddiqui/.continuum
drwx------   3 khsiddiqui  staff     102 30 Jul  2010 /Users/khsiddiqui/.cups
drwx------  10 khsiddiqui  staff     340  2 Apr 17:26 /Users/khsiddiqui/.dropbox
-rw-r--r--   1 khsiddiqui  staff    2525 12 Apr 16:56 /Users/khsiddiqui/.enstaller4rc
drwxr-xr-x   9 khsiddiqui  staff     306  9 Apr 22:25 /Users/khsiddiqui/.ipython
drwxr-xr-x   4 khsiddiqui  staff     136 12 Apr 16:57 /Users/khsiddiqui/.matplotlib
-rw-r--r--   1 khsiddiqui  staff     340 12 Apr 01:12 /Users/khsiddiqui/.profile
-rw-r--r--   1 khsiddiqui  staff     251 28 Mar 13:45 /Users/khsiddiqui/.profile-anaconda.bak
drwxr-xr-x  15 khsiddiqui  staff     510  2 Apr 17:21 /Users/khsiddiqui/.rstudio-desktop
drwxr-xr-x   6 khsiddiqui  staff     204 20 Oct 19:21 /Users/khsiddiqui/.subversion
-rw-------   1 khsiddiqui  staff     625  9 Apr 21:33 /Users/khsiddiqui/.viminfo`

Comment: 1) Add the suggested lines to `~/.bashrc`

2) What is the output of `env | grep PATH` ? (Add this info to your question, not in a comment.)

Comment: Hey @Jonathan, I'm new to coding. What commands would I enter? Do you mean  `~/.bashrc export PATH=/Users/khsiddiqui/torch/install/bin:$PATH` for instance?

Comment: 1) There is a file in your home directory called `.bashrc`. Edit with a text editor (for example the Canopy editor, not a word processor like Word), adding the 3 export lines quoted in your question.

Comment: 2) Open a Terminal. Type `env | grep PATH`. Copy the output to your clipboard and paste that into a code block at the end of your original question.

Comment: do you know where the .bashrc file would be located? having trouble locating it through canopy editor. I could do a search through Terminal. I can't immediately see it within usr.

Comment: Ah, yes, Mac is nastily stubborn about not showing you "hidden" files (whose filename begins with a period). Easiest would be from the Canopy Python panel: type `cd`, press enter, then `%edit .bashrc`, then press enter.

Comment: It seems that you might not have a .bashrc file. Let's see what profile file(s) you do have. Open a Terminal, then type `ls -ld ~/.*` . What is the output?

Comment: doesn't seem to be a file called .bashrc

Comment: But you do have a `.profile` file, so make the same changes there (append 3 lines), using the same suggested techniques (either with `%edit` from Canopy Python panel, or with `edit` from Terminal as suggested by Tony.

Comment: the 3 lines have been added. Do I need to save .profile after adding the lines?

Comment: Yes. They have not actually been added until you save.

Comment: what's the command for saving the .profile file.  "%save .profile"     ?

Comment: It sounds like you have the file open in the Canopy editor. Just as with any editor or word processor etc, use the File menu's Save command (shortcut Cmd+S). BTW, you will need to take the initiative to experiment, as nobody will be able to walk you through every step. Please start by readin the user guide's getting started: http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/gui_overview.html . Also, it would be useful to find yourself a geek buddy.

Comment: thank you Jonathan, Torch is now installed! Beers on me if you're ever in Manchester, UK.

Comment: Excellent. I did hike through/across Manchester many years ago, so I'll accept your offer via my time machine!

Comment: haha, gr8! h.g. wells would've liked the sound of that.

Answer (score 6):

i had a similar problem and solved it, maybe it could help others.

Here was the end of the second installation script, and the command "th" wasn't working:

```
Not updating your shell profile.
You might want to
add the following lines to your shell profile:

. /Users/myusername/torch/install/bin/torch-activate
```

This article explains how your shell profile is organized: https://serverfault.com/questions/110065/what-profile-is-my-current-shell-using

I realized in my user folder /Users/myusername/ i had a ".bash_profile" file, i pasted the line ". /Users/myusername/torch/install/bin/torch-activate" inside but didn't work (command "th" no recognized in terminal).

**So in the same /Users/myusername/ folder i created a ".profile" file** and pasted the line ". /Users/myusername/torch/install/bin/torch-activate" inside.

Then the command "th" works fine ;)

Comment: This is easily done by executing at the terminal:  `echo ". /Users/$(id -un)/torch/install/bin/torch-activate" > ~/.profile`, assuming that you installed torch to the default location. (Otherwise, just specify the correct path to the torch-activate file.)

Comment: I created ".profile" and pasted the line but still "th" is not recognized.. any more tips?

Answer (score 0):

First, IPython may be installed but not seen by the install process.

If you enter `which ipython` at a shell prompt it will tell you where it is installed. Then `echo $PATH` will display your PATH variable which should contain the directory that contains IPython. If it isn't then you will have to edit the PATH statement in your .bashrc file to add it.

Second, `.bashrc` is a file that is run by the shell when it starts up and should be in your home directory so enter `cd` at a shell prompt and you will be there. Then use a text editor such as Text Edit to edit it. In your case you don't have a `.bashrc` file, instead some things are being set in a file called `.profile`. You should probably check the contents of that.

Finally, I wouldn't run any of these commands from within IPython. Only run them (and the Torch install process) from the shell.

Further, I notice you have a file with the name "anaconda" in it. Have you installed 'Anaconda'?

Comment: Hey Tony, do you want me to type the three lines immediately after hitting 'cd' and [enter]? how would I exit 'cd' afterwards.